# Not able delete edit or delete group in alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am not able to delete or edit the group from alfresco share.
Once I add the group and tried to delete or edit then failed..
I checked my console and got the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
```

(Forbidden)  http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/share/proxy/alfresco/api/groups/TestGroup

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null 
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPut.failureCallback.fn 
_failureHandler 
YAHOO.util.Connect.handleTransactionResponse 
(anonymous function)
```

I also configured openam

How can I solve this error ??? Please help

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: alfresco version 4.2.f